# List TODOs which have specific property

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to list all `TODO` entries which have specific property value.
For example:

- I have many `TODO` entries which are listed beneath `Collage` heading.
- `Collage` heading have property `CATEGORY` set to `school`.
- There are multiple headers with corresponding value of `CATEGORY` property in single `org` file.

I currently know of two useful `org-mode` functionalities which could help here.

- I can make a sparse tree of all `collage` headings using `M-x org-sparse-tree p CATEGORY collage`.
- Also know how to make list of all `TODO` entries using `M-x org-agenda t`.

How to combine those two?
Or how to do it more elegant way?

Comment: The following link contains examples of how to search property drawers using the `org-agenda.el` library:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  See also:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties  I am assuming the original poster is referring to a property drawer underneath `:PROPERTIES:` that looks like `:CATEGORY: school` and, if so the OP could evaluate the following expression in a `*scratch*` buffer:  `(org-tags-view nil "CATEGORY={school}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [org-agenda-custom-commands](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) is for.  It lets you add additional agenda view to `org-agenda`.  Here we attach "S" to a search for all `TODO` items whose `CATEGORY` is `school`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("S" "School"
               tags-todo "+CATEGORY=\"school\""))
```

Access it with `M-x org-agenda S`.  There are many, many options allowing you to customize exactly what get shown.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want. Actually, I knew that `org-mode` has an elegant solution but I couldn't find it. :)

Comment: But... There is a little problem here. It works well if I evaluate it in scratch buffer after initialization but when I put it inside `org-mode-hook` (where all my `org-mode` settings reside) it doesn't. In which loading phase one should execute it?

Comment: I've figured it out. Org agenda could be called before `org-mode` activation, it means before `org-mode-hook`, so one should set this outside that hook. And since `org-agenda-custom-commands` is free variable by default one should do it through `setq` like so: ```(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
             '(("S" "School"
               tags-todo "+CATEGORY=\"school\""))```